# Extract hours between two date on bigquery standard sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract data from between date and time range using StandardSQL in Bigquery

Basically what I do is, take the data from between defined date to the current date and from 9 am at a defined date to 9 am current date.

I tried to use this query but it only returns the data from the 9 am defined date to only 11;59 pm that defined date, I can't find the data from the current date. But if I removed the constraint `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP(DATETIME(registration_started_at, 'Asia/Jakarta'))) >= 9` it can returns the date range I want but not the time range

```
SELECT * 
from `table`
WHERE (DATE(DATETIME(registration_started_at, 'Asia/Jakarta')) BETWEEN '2021-04-30' AND DATE(DATETIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'Asia/Jakarta')))
ORDER BY registration_updated_at ASC) a
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DATETIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'Asia/Jakarta')) < 9
AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP(DATETIME(registration_started_at, 'Asia/Jakarta'))) >= 9
```

```
Sample Data
+---------+------------------------------+
|   ID    |   registration_started_at    |
+---------+------------------------------+
|    1    |  2021-04-29 07:44:08.864 UTC |    
|    2    |  2021-04-30 11:46:58.451 UTC |
|    3    |  2021-04-30 20:10:27.748 UTC |   
|    4    |  2021-04-30 20:39:47.206 UTC |  
+---------+------------------------------+
```

Expected Output (local timezone)--not the real output of the time column above

```
+---------+------------------------------+
|   ID    |   registration_started_at    |
+---------+------------------------------+
|    2    |  2021-04-30T09:04:52.001000  |    
|    3    |  2021-04-30T11:02:43.232000  |
|    4    |  2021-05-01T08:00:10.569000  |    
+---------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your code is quite confusing, because neither `date` or `datetime` represent a timezone, so they are assume to be in local time.

Comment: For such tasks date and time should be considered together, because 10AM of tomorrow is greater than 10PM of today. Do filter on datetimes, not date parts

Comment: @ebuzz168 . . . UTC is not `datetime`, it is `TIMESTAMP`.  You haven't clarified the issue about the data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is rather confusing.  `DATETIME` does not have a time zone, so I don't really see why you need to extract the date using a time zone.

I *think* you just want a range from '2021-04-30 09:00:00' through (but not including '2021-05-01 09:00:00').

If so, subtract 9 hours from the `DATETIME` value and compare to the date:

```
DATE(DATETIME_ADD(registration_started_at, INTERVAL -9 HOUR)) = DATE('2021-04-30')
```

Comment: I want a range from '2021-04-30 09:00:00' through  '2021-05-01 09:00:00'

Comment: Timezone plays role since `current_date` is timezone dependent. But it accepts timezone as argument without any additional computation, the original OP's date operations are cumbersome.

Comment: @ebuzz168 `some date` will fall between `Day A 09:00:00` and `Day B 09:00:00` if and only if `some day - 9 hours` falls between `Day A` and `Day B`. So for *not including* the upper boundary and for single day this answer is the most straightforward and simple solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes!, thank you sir. Do you have a recommendation where I can learn more about this time operation in standardsql/bigquery?

Comment: @ebuzz168 . . . This is less about the time functions than a simple confusion about 9 hours versus time zones.  It just takes practice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff anyway, how do you read this; you take the `registration_started_at ` at 9 hours before the `registration_started_at ` and where the DATE is `2021-04-30`?

Comment: @ebuzz168 . . . Subtract nine hours and extract the date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The part that it returns the `2021-05-01` plus nine hours as well is still confusing me